# Posting a html page using c++

Tags: html, c++, http

I'm trying to post a html page using c++. I built a class using the sockets that implements tcpsoketing.
I checked it and it worked. So i think my problem is in what I send :

```
string s = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>home.html</title></head><body><form name='input' action='login.html' method='get'>user name: <input type='text' name='user'><br>password: <input type='text' name='password'><input type='submit' value='Submit'> </form></body></html>";

string str="POST /home.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1:22225\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.66 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Length: 2048"+s;
```

Comment: POSTing html to an html url is extremely odd, what are you trying to do? ... As for your HTTP request, the line delimiter before the Connection: header is invalid (multiple \r\n), you specify urlencoded content but the content is not url encoded, you need 2 * \r\n to delimit headers and the request body

Comment: I'm trying to write a code that by sending it i will be able to write the url in the browser and get that page

Comment: As  in a web server? you want to enter a url in a browser, hit your socket app and have it return an html response ... or ?

Comment: Can you add some code showing how exactly you are doing the whole POSTING process?

Comment: He's probably trying to create a server that echos whatever HTML  is POSTed to it. The .html extension in home.html is probably a trick to make browsers render the page as HTML instead of plain text.

Answer (score 2):

Your suspicions are correct. Your request message is malformed. See RFC 7230, section 3: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3

> ```
>  HTTP-message   = start-line
> ```

```
                  *( header-field CRLF )
                  CRLF
                  [ message-body ]
```

Pay close attention to how many line endings you need to use after each header-field.

Tip: the header block and the message body are separated by `CRLF CRLF`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an empty line between the headers and the body (specified in RFC 7230) e.g.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache/1.3.29 (Unix) PHP/4.3.4
Content-Length: 123456
Content-Language: de
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE html><html></html>
```